# Java ResultSet closing early

Tags: java, swing, sqlite

Im having a issue that i cant seem to figure out. I am making a signup and login in java with swing and connecting it to a sqlite database with java.sql.* and jdbc. When i try to login after signing up it shows me the error ResultSet closed. can someone help me. I believe the issue resides in one of these 
If not there here is the link to the project
https://bitbucket.org/jrdevtech/library-management-system/src
i believe it would be in AppGui i only used ResultSet in isFirstUse method and the two button actions

---

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

```
            PreparedStatement prep = null;
            try {
                String query = "INSERT INTO newuser"
                        + "(name, dob, phonenumber, username, 
                            password, uuid)"
                        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                connection = databaseConnection.dataConnector();
                prep = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                prep.setString(1, txtName.getText());
                prep.setString(2, txtDob.getText());
                prep.setString(3, txtPhone.getText());
                prep.setString(4, txtUsername.getText());
                prep.setString(5, txtPassword.getPassword().toString());
                prep.setString(6, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                prep.executeUpdate();

            }catch(Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}
            finally{
                try {
                    if(prep != null) {
                        prep.close();
                    }
                    if(connection != null) {
                        connection.close();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

---

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    PreparedStatement prep = null;

```
int correct = 0;

try {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM newuser WHERE username=? AND 
    password=?";
    connection = databaseConnection.dataConnector();
    prep = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    prep.setString(1, txtLoginUsername.getText());
    prep.setString(2, txtLoginPassword.getPassword().toString());
    ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rs.getString("username"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rs.getString("password"));
        if(correct == 2) {isLoggedIn = true; 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Are Logged In");}
        else if(correct != 2) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "Invalid Login Credentials");}
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getString("username"));
    }catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
            }
            finally {
                try {

                    if(prep != null) {
                        prep.close();
                    }
                    if(connection != null) {
                        connection.close();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}
            }
        }
    });
```

---

Comment: You should post a [mcve]. A link to your project is not appropriate.

Comment: Please paste your code into the question itself, nicely formatted. [The help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) contains more tips for how to improve your question and your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Why do you think the problem with the ResultSet might lie in the first method? That method does not even use a ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the resultset was not finding anything with the query so therefore closing i just rewrote the query a bit and redid how i saved the saved the password since it was comparing differently with the password field